# Puppet: (Server 8) Using binary data in stored in hiera results in "Error 500 on SERVER"

Tags: puppet, hiera

Our site is migrating from puppet6 to puppet8, and we've encountered an issue with storing binary data in hiera.

The original (binary) data file was encrypted with eyaml:

```
$ eyaml encrypt -f binary.data > binary.data.eyaml
```

and the resulted eyaml file was included in a Hiera yaml file as:

```
test::func::data: >
    ENC[PKCS7,.....
    ...]
```

When using this code:

```
test::func{ 'hello':
     data    =>  lookup('binary::data')
}
```

with:

```
define test::func(
  Binary $data
) {
}
```

results in an error:

```
Test::Func[hello]: parameter 'data' expects a Binary value, got String
```

however using type "String" (which works on puppet6)

```
define test::func(
  String $data
) {
}
```

results in:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on
SERVER: Server Error: Failed to serialize Puppet::Resource::Catalog
for 'puppetserver': Could not render to
Puppet::Network::Format[rich_data_json]: source sequence is
illegal/malformed utf-8
```

This is a behavior change moving from 6 to 8.

Any suggestions as to how to get around this issue?

Comment: How are your binary data represented in the Hiera data store?  Can you add an example to the question?

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger - the data is encrypted (an AD key tab)

Comment: The question was not what *kind* of data it is, but how it is *represented* in the external data file.  I don't expect you to present your actual encrypted keytab or other sensitive data, of course, but I do want to see something representative of the form.  As it stands, you've given us only half the picture.  This is, in effect, a request for a [mre].

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger - I've enhanced the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

The YAML hiera backend only supports [basic types](https://yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#basic_types), and [Binary type](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_data_binary.html) value is created with a base64 encoded string.

```rb
function Binary.new(
  String $base64_str,
  Optional[Base64Format] $format
)
```

1. [Configure hiera to cast specific values with the required type using lookup_options](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/hiera_merging#setting_lookup_options_to_refine_the_result_of_a_lookup-make-hiera-return-data-by-casting).
2. Encode the data with base64.
3. Encrypt the base64 value.

Based on your use case, in the "common" control-repo hiera file add the following to ensure the lookup value is returned as Binary:

```yaml
lookup_options:
  binary::data:
    convert_to: Binary
```

Then base64 encode the binary data and encrypt it:

```bash
base64 < binary.data | eyaml encrypt -l binary::data --stdin
```

The output should look something like:

```
binary::data: ENC[PKCS7,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]

OR

binary::data: >
  ENC[PKCS7,MIIBeQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBajCCAWYCAQAxggEhMIIBHQIBAD
  AFMAACAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEA2/1rNGJbO10rQvPYq2aiLCzeIX
  Vdx/ZAzD+mFJ/IM8i4QYgiW0EwVPpvqwJUiy9iyJ3yd3lD8PJLS6c3/22ta5
  LVOR50eKRUPGSQuZ7fYGfdHpCwTH/kWz2omJrr+sm2ChW2YrUrTVninz6BhB
  jCBzSWlK9HJmejX4uuZdTu6YZn5LU123hyy9kW1mmtDCCjNfH3dM8K3EQ38f
  fv55hG4cIOHGOIuxV9J0LS9AAtuOB4sKMmh5u0/ZO6HyOUz5OniniKqZZsRM
  I3UGYpOqA0A9HxAcmFsySBSVsSwncYfZR3cEKFblfHqGorPJAccNj78XPrWO
  i5AxjcyIleQwqmPzA8BgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHQYJYIZIAWUDBAEqBBBk3e5h2V
  XAjGs5veW3o4EkgBD9bpPwo/f9bPGKyL9Ufvv9]
```

Copy and paste one of those into your hiera yaml file.

Note: if you interpolate a Binary variable's value in puppet code as a string, it will return the base64 value (e.g. `notify { "${binary_var}": }`)

Comment: this doesn't work for me - I must be missing something, and the problems I am having are almost a new question in themselves.

Simply thou, if I make the change you suggested then I get an error "Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, The convert_to lookup_option for key 'profile::testing2::data' raised error: invalid base64 on node ..."

if I convert the file to base64, then encrypt it I also get the "invalid base64".

Comment: @greg updated answer with all steps tested on Puppet 8.